# Installed go with hombrew, can find $GOROOT causing package failures

Tags: unit-testing, go

I installed Go with homebrew and it usually works. Following the tutorial here on creating [serverless api in Go](https://read.acloud.guru/serverless-golang-api-with-aws-lambda-34e442385a6a). When I try to run the unit tests, I get the following error:

```
# _/Users/pro/Documents/Code/Go/ServerLess
main_test.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/strechr/testify/assert" in any of:
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.2/libexec/src/github.com/strechr/testify/assert (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/pro/go/src/github.com/strechr/testify/assert (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    _/Users/pro/Documents/Code/Go/ServerLess [setup failed]
Pros-MBP:ServerLess Santi$ echo $GOROOT
```

I have installed the test library with : go get github.com/stretchr/testify

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Also confusing is when I run `echo $GOPATH` it doesnt return anything. same goes for `echo $GOROOT`

Comment: How are you building/testing your package?  (`GOROOT` doesn't need to be set, and `GOPATH` defaults to `$HOME/go`)

Comment: Run go test in the folder in terminal @JimB

Comment: You have a typo in your import path: `strechr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try/verify:

- As JimB notes, starting with Go 1.8 the GOPATH env var is now optional and has default values: https://rakyll.org/default-gopath/
- While you don't need to set it, the directory does need to have the Go workspace structure: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces
- Once that is created, create your source file in something like: $GOPATH/src/github.com/DataKid/sample/main.go
- `cd` into that directory, and re-run the `go get` commands:

  - `go get -u -v github.com/stretchr/testify`
  - `go get -u -v github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda`
- Then try running the test command again: `go test -v`

The `-v` option is for verbose output, the `-u` option ensures you download the latest package versions (https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies).